# Setup MAAS with UEFI

Tags: boot, uefi, maas

I am seting up an Ubuntu MAAS server to install my cluster. The nodes in the cluster can only boot from UEFI, So I set up the (external) DHCP server with this config:

```
dhcp-boot=grubnetx64.efi.signed,up01,192.168.1.137
```

But it didn't work, the file doesn't exist:

[image]

When I change `grubnetx64.efi.signed` to `pxelinux.0` it works on a Virtual Machine, but i can't use that on my cluster for it only boots from UEFI:

[image]

The Maas server is sort of working because it does download the file, but can simply not execute it:

[image]

I've looked in the documentation to set it up for UEFI boot, but couldn't find anything that helped me.

Comment: what version of Maas did you used? Just started with a fresh MAAS 2.1 and UEFI is working well by default (no specific changes). I've got few servers only in UEFI and other that boot in legacy mode. No issue so far.

Comment: I think the problem was that I was using experimental computer boards where UEFI apparently isn't support that great.

Answer (score 0):

I used MaaS 2.3.x and **bootx64.efi**. This works for me.

If you were interesting what the resource are available to use, you may refer to the files provided by the package **maas-rack-controller**, e.g. checking the files under **/var/lib/maas/boot-resources** of your MaaS server.

Answer (score 0):

When MAAS manages DHCP, it transparently detects whether the machine is booting EFI or legacy and serves up the right files. Since you are using an external DHCP server, you need to make that differentiation in your external DHCP server, and configure it to send the right files.

That said, I would recommend you use MAAS run DHCP. That would always give you the best results.